# There is Run time error in making 2D Array

Tags: c++, runtime-error, c++14

```
using namespace std;

int dp[1001][1001];

int main() {

  ...
}
```

In this case, there is no run time error.

However,

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string A, B;

   cin >> A >> B;

   int dp[1001][1001];

   ....
}
```

If I make code like this, there is run time error.
Even first line of main function didn't work.

Could you let me know why this error happend?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: It helps to say what the runtime error actually is.  Although in this case it's pretty obvious.  You are declaring an array too large for your stack.  When you declared the array as global, it lives outside the stack.  If you need it to exist only within the context of a stack frame, then you should allocate it dynamically.

Comment: If this is windows the default stack is 1 MB. 1001 * 1001 * 4 is larger than that.

Comment: You are asking for a 4 MB stack. If the platform you are running does not grow the stack as necessary (most likely using a MMU to do so) then you most likely are overflowing the stack. And here we are on SO talking about it.

Comment: Thank you guys. It's really helpful to me. I love you guys and I love stackoverflow.com!!

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable before `main()`, it is *global* variable, which is located in static memory. If you declare it inside `main()`, it is a *local* variable, which (in practice, although not mandated by C++ standard) is located on the *stack*. Only a small portion of the total memory is allocated to the stack. If you accede its size, you get *stack overflow*. That's what happened in your case, because `int dp[1001][1001]` typically takes about 4 MB or 8 MB, depending on `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: *In static memory*. Can you please elaborate on static memory? Like if it is not on the stack then where it resides, if it is a global variable?.

Comment: [Storage class specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) -- 3rd time is the charm.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize variable with global variable, computer saves it to heap.

however, local variables are saved in stack.

So

===

using namespace std;

int main() { string A, B;

cin >> A >> B;

int dp[1001][1001];

===

prints out an error. (int dp[1001][1001] is too big to save in the stack)

So, when you wanna save big variables in run-time (not global variable) just use 'dynamic allocation'. It also save variables to heap, and i think it will works.

Comment: `When you initialize variable with global variable, computer saves it to heap` - that is nonsense.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll remember what you told me :)